# guzzlehtp и мультипоточность

Tags: php, guzzle

Всем привет!)
Возник вопрос, в котором что то не могу нормально разобраться.
Есть массив ссылок:

```
$arr_links=['link1', 'link2', 'link3'];
```

Как с помощью `Guzzle` одновременно отправить запрос на каждую ссылку, и собрать все ответы в массив?
спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/client.html#sending-requests-in-parallel):

```
$responses = $client->send(array(
    $client->get('link1'),
    $client->get('link2'),
    $client->get('link3')
));
```

Или [пакеты](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/batching/batching.html#batching):

```
use Guzzle\Batch\Batch;
use Guzzle\Http\BatchRequestTransfer;

// BatchRequestTransfer acts as both the divisor and transfer strategy
$transferStrategy = new BatchRequestTransfer(10);
$divisorStrategy = $transferStrategy;

$batch = new Batch($transferStrategy, $divisorStrategy);

// Add some requests to the batch queue
$batch->add($client->get('link1'))
    ->add($client->get('link2'))
    ->add($client->get('link3'));

// Flush the queue and retrieve the flushed items
$arrayOfTransferredRequests = $batch->flush();
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в Guzzle6  что то не могу разобрать как правильно сделать  http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html#streams